# Firewalld block all input/output connections and only allow some outgoing ports

Tags: fedora, firewalld

I am trying to set firewalld in Fedora 36 to block all input and output connections and only allow certain outgoing communication.

1. The computer is not a server of any kind so we want to block all incoming connections.
2. I only want to allow a few selected ports to be able to send traffic out.

**This is what I have been able to come up with:**

1. Default zone for all interfaces set to: **public**
2. Default public zone target set to: **DROP**
3. No services, ports, protocols... are configured in the public zone.
4. IPv6 is not enabled on the computer at all.
5. The computer has a static IPv4 so dhcp ports are not required.
6. I am testing this on a fresh Fedora machine with no additional networking software installed.
7. After each change the firewall is reloaded.
8. The rest is configured using direct rules:

```
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 2 -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 3 -o lo -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 4 -j DROP
```

**This does not work. I am not able to load any website.**

If I add NEW to the --state rule above, I can load websites.
`ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`
But if I then remove all the --dport rules, wait until `ss -tupan` shows no waiting connections, I can still load new websites no matter that no ports are explicitly allowed with these resulting rules:

```
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 2 -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 3 -o lo -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 4 -j DROP
```

Changing the --dport rules from ACCEPT to DROP does prevent websites from loading but that is not what I want.

My understanding was that without the --dport rules everything should be dropped and only the --dport rules allow specific ports. So I should not need the NEW state.

How do I make it behave like that?
Thanks.

Comment: Your stateful rule (accepting only `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` traffics) belongs to the INPUT chain instead, although AFAIK firewalld itself add/use it already. Probably the problem is that you forgot DNS often / essentially uses UDP.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the UDP port 53 fixed it and I did not even have to move the stateful rule into the INPUT chain.

Comment: About the stateful rule. I have seen it in the OUTPUT chain in some other examples. https://serverfault.com/questions/618164/block-outgoing-connections-on-rhel7-centos7-with-firewalld But it works without the rule too. Is there a good reason to have the rule in the OUTPUT chain?

Comment: Basically it works as a complement anyway. For example if you have a rule allowing tcp dport 22 for ssh in INPUT, and you don't want to add a corresponding stateless one (tcp sport 22) in OUTPUT for replies, then you can have that in OUTPUT as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.